# How to automatically take a '/' (slash) in input field using reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, mask, react-class-based-component

How can I format an input to place a slash before the value that the user enters, so that the user cannot delete it because it is already formatted that way. I'm trying to add functionality to input /characters fields so as when the users enters digits, slashes "/" get automatically added before.

I'm new in React, so I don't any idea of how I can resolve that, please helpe me

An Example of the result I want to resolve

[image]

```
 mascaraUserName = (text) => {
        const selectedData_ = this.state.form;
        formated = text;
          if(formated.length==1){
            //formated = text +'/';
            if(selectedData_.userName.indexOf('/') == -1){
              formated = text +'/';
            }
    
          }
    
          console.log(formated);
        // this.setState({ form: myRef }); 
      }

<Col xs={24} sm={24} md={24} lg={24}>
            <FormItem {...formItemLayout}
              label={intl.formatMessage({ id: `maintenace.link.userName` })}>
              {getFieldDecorator(`disable`, {
                initialValue: "https://"
                  ? "https://"
                  : ""
              })(<Input style={{ color: "#3e3e3ed9"}} disabled="disabled"/>)}
              {getFieldDecorator(`userName`, {
                initialValue: selectedData_.userName
                  ? selectedData_.userName
                  : ""
              })(<Input className="inputLink" name="userName" ref={this.myRef} onChange={this.mascaraUserName} placeholder={intl.formatMessage({
                id: `maintenace.link.nicknameIntructions`
              })} />)}
            </FormItem>
          </Col>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the input controlled and then intercept any change that tries to remove the initial "/":

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-danny-9sk9mt?file=/src/App.js:23-351)

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [link, setLink] = useState("/");

  return (
    <input
      value={link}
      onChange={(e) => {
        const value = e.target.value;
        if (!value.startsWith("/")) e.preventDefault();
        else setLink(value);
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

**Edit**: Didn't notice this was react native (it's not tagged as it) but I'll leave my answer here since you can probably still use the logic to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you! No, It's about ReactJS in class component, but I trying with your answer right now (It was my mistake when I asked the question)